# formalising diagonlazation when trying to disprove that a set is countable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

first sorry for the very weak title. english is not my main language.
so im trying to solve the next qeustion

> prove that the set of all functions from $\omega$ to $\omega$ is uncountable
>
> $S=\{ f \vert f:\omega \rightarrow \omega \}$

so first i said that its equivelent to the set of all functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$ and tried 2 methods.

1. that power of this set is $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}= \aleph_0^{\aleph_0}$ and since $\aleph_0 > 2$ then $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}= \aleph_0^{\aleph_0}>2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph$ and since $\aleph$ is not countable we can say that $S$ is not countable.

    i'd like to know if its fine what i did here, I tend to mix between cardinals and ordinals
2. i used proof by contradiction, suppose that $S$ is countable that there is a function $F:S \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ injective.
   so we can number the functions from $S$ like this

    $f_1$

    $f_2$

    $f_3$

    etc.

    and since every function is a set of orderd pairs we can list like this

    $f_1 = \{ (1,a_{1,1}) , (2,a_{1,2})...\}$

    $f_2 = \{ (1,a_{2,1}) , (2,a_{2,2})...\}$

    $f_3 = \{ (1,a_{3,1}) , (2,a_{3,2})...\}$ etc.

    and then defince a new function $g=\{ (i,b)\vert i\in \mathbb{N} \wedge (b=a_{i,i}+1) \}$ then since $a_{i,i}\in\mathbb{N}$ for each $i\in\mathbb{N}$ we get a function $g:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$, but since this function is different from any function $f_i$ because there is at least one ordered pair that is different, then $g$ is not in the set in contradiction to the definition of $S$

the logic behind these proofs is fine (I hope) but is the formal writing is good? any review will help thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your proof in (1) is fine, except that $\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}$: exponentiation preserves $\geq$ but not necessarily $>$.

Your proof in (2) is also fine. You don't need a contradiction there, more directly: you're showing that every function from $\omega$ to $\omega^\omega$ is not surjective.

Other than this, it's fine. You can improve (2) by not referring to the ordered pairs representation of each function. Simply take $f_0,f_1,\dots$ in $\omega^\omega$, and define $g(i)=f_i(i)+1$, then for every $i$, $g(i)\neq f_i(i)$ so $g\neq f_i$. Therefore the list is not exhaustive, so $\omega^\omega$ is not countable.

Comment: i was looking for a way to do this without the ordered pairs, thanks
can you explain why  exponentiation preserves ≥ but not necessarily >.